# Replace server name in UNC path using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, unc

I'm working with the `XML` configuration file which contains the `UNC` path:

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content $file
$UNC = ($config.configuration.unc.value)
```

Where `$UNC` then equals `\\dev.local\share\shared`

I need to replace the server name `dev.local` (whose name is unknown) in the `$UNC` variable with `prod.local` using Powershell.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-replace` with a regular expression:

```
PS C:\Users\robin> $unc = '\\dev.local\share\shared'
PS C:\Users\robin> $server = 'prod.local'
PS C:\Users\robin> $newUnc = $unc -replace '(\\\\)([a-z\.]+)(\\*)', "`$1$server`$3"
PS C:\Users\robin> $unc
\\dev.local\share\shared
PS C:\Users\robin> $newUnc
\\prod.local\share\shared
```

The regular expression is matching 3 groups:

1. the initial `\\`
2. anything between 1. upto the next `\`
3. the first `\` and anything after

Group 2 is replace with the value of the variable `$server` set to `prod.local` in this example.

The replace syntax uses double quotes so `$server` is evaluated, and the backticks around the capture groups make them work as substitutions from the regular expression.

Comment: The server name 'dev.local' is uknown

Comment: `prod.local` is also a variable that need's to be put in `$1prod.local$3`